# How do I block any entries to a site that come from a google result?

Tags: .htaccess

one of my clients has a CRM on their site which has a publicly accessible documents folder which needs to be setup this way so the can link to it from other sites but only for those who have login access. Anyway it seems google has found and listed these documents in their search results (nothing super secure, just company newsletters etc) however they would like it if someone clicks the link in google it is rejected. Can this be done with a htaccess rule or within cpanel?

I was thinking something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.google\.com/$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I went with the following and it seemed to do the job as required:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*google.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*yahoo.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*linkedin.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*flickr.*
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Request has a Referer field that should contain the website from which someone is entering your website. You can check for Google and send them a 404.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14

These are easy to spoof and some anonymous browsers will strip this information off any request made. But it should stop the average user from visiting the website through Google.

Comment: OK thanks. How does this sound: RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.google\.com/$
RewriteRule .* - [F]

Comment: I know my limits. :P Check out this site.
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess14.shtml

What you've written looks okay though.

Comment: Thanks, I modified it a little and came up with the answer from your suggestions. Thanks again.